# Angular2 Karma unitTesting Async function with TimeOut

Tags: angular, unit-testing, timeout, karma-jasmine

Im working on angular2 web app.
I would like to test my function thet is reconnecting server connection after some time. It looks like this (not actual code) :

```
reconnect() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.connection.stop()
        this.cnnect(); // Logic here
        }, this.connectionTimeout);
    this.connectionTimeout+=this.connectionTimoutDeley;
}
```

Its fired through subject thet is controlling connectionStatus, if its set to Disconected im restarting it manually to end of times.

I would like to unit test it, if the timeout and deley relly happens. But its asynhrounous and i dont know how to test it....
My soulution thet dont work:

```
 it('should deley reconnect process', fakeAsync (() => {
            //Arrange 
            var timeSpanForFirstReconnect;
            var timeSpanForSecondReconnect;            
            var actDone = false;
            service.setimeouts(1000, 100000, 100);
            //service.getConnectionStatus().subscribe(status => {
            //    //Assert
            //    if (actDone) {
            //        expect(timeSpanForSecondReconnect).toBeGreaterThan(timeSpanForFirstReconnect);
            //        done();
            //    }
            //});
            //Act
            timeSpanForFirstReconnect = performance.now();
            statusSubject.next(new ConnectionStatus(ConnectionStatuses.Disconected));
            tick();
            timeSpanForFirstReconnect = performance.now() - timeSpanForFirstReconnect;
            timeSpanForSecondReconnect = performance.now();
            statusSubject.next(new ConnectionStatus(ConnectionStatuses.Disconected));
            tick();
            timeSpanForSecondReconnect = performance.now() - timeSpanForSecondReconnect;
            console.log(timeSpanForFirstReconnect + '  ------   ' + timeSpanForSecondReconnect);
            expect(timeSpanForSecondReconnect).toBeGreaterThan(timeSpanForFirstReconnect);
            actDone = true;


        }));
```